# Retrieve RDF resource with sub nodes using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf

I need to retrieve all "properties" associated to a subject, identified by specific predicates, using one SPARQL query.  I specifically avoid using the terms "export triples", as I don't necessarily need `CONSTRUCT` (either `CONSTRUCT` or `SELCET` could do).

Some "properties" are nodes themselves (possibly blank nodes), and need to be "recursively" retrieved.  The set of predicates is known (I have a comprehensive list of them, they are all in the same prefix and they are all of those with that prefix).  The predicate to "recurse" over are a subset of them.

```
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/ex/> .
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .
ex:toExport
    a ex:SomeClass ;            # to retrieve, as in rdf: namespace
    :pred-1 "Some value" ;      # to retrieve "as is"
    :pred-2 42 ;                # to retrieve "as is"
    :pred-3 [                   # blank-node to be retrieved as a whole
        :pred-1 "..." ;
        :pred-2 1024 
    ] ;
    :pred-4 [
        :pred-3 [               # "sub" blank-node to be retrieved as a whole
            :pred-1 "..." ;
            :pred-2 1024 
        ] 
    ] ;
    :pred-5 [                   # same for a "sub-list"
        :pred-6 ( ex:something ex:else ) 
    ] ;
    :pred-7 ex:subOne .         # "sub-property" can be a non-blank node...

ex:subOne                       # ...defined as a resource of its own
    :pred-1 "Value" ;
    :pred-2 0 .
```

In the example above, I need to retrieve the triples with the predicates `:pred-1` and `:pred-2` (simple values), `:pred-3` (the value of which is a blank node with 2 triples in these example), `:pred-4` (a blank node itself, with an extra blank node), etc.  The `:pred-7` is interesting as it shows all "sub-nodes" are not necessarily blank nodes.

The following query is the closest I found matching my requirements, but it uses a regex on the string value of the IRIs, which I would like to avoid for queries on large data sets:

```
CONSTRUCT {
    ?s  ?p   ?o .
    ?o  ?pp  ?oo .
    ?oo ?ppp ?ooo .
}
WHERE {
{
    ?s ?p ?o .
    FILTER ( regex(str(?p), "^(http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#|http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#)") )
    OPTIONAL
    {
        ?o ?pp ?oo .
        FILTER ( regex(str(?pp), "^(http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#|http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#)") )
        OPTIONAL
        {
            ?oo ?ppp ?ooo .
            FILTER ( regex(str(?ppp), "^(http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#|http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#)") )
        }
    }
}
```

The set of predicates is something like 20 different predicates, so it is manageable to list them somehow, but not if it is in a combinatorial way.

Comment: I don't see much potential to optimize it, but you could at least query for the distinct properties first in a separate sub-SELECT query such that it'S only executed once. The rest of the query is as expected, the generation of a sub-graph of depth 3

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for the regex: if your goal is to simply make it easier to read you could do something along these lines:

```
FILTER(STRSTARTS(STR(?p), STR(rdf:)) || STRSTARTS(STR(?p), STR(shacl:)))
```

This saves you having to use a long regex with the full namespace IRIs, and moreover moves the logical-OR out of the regex and into the SPARQL filter logic itself (which is possibly more efficient).

Apart from that, I don't immediately see an easy way to improve upon this in a single SPARQL query. However, if you're willing to compromise and do some post-processing on your result you can get quite close, with a much simpler query.

Normally, this kind of thing is served quite well using a simple `DESCRIBE` query:

```
DESCRIBE ex:toExport
```

However, there's two requirements in your scenario that make this more difficult:

1. `:pred-7`'s value should also be returned: `DESCRIBE` typically only returns the blank node-closure for the resource being described, so this won't be a complete answer.
2. only certain properties should be returned: `DESCRIBE` typically returns *all* properties.

For the first problem, we can extend the `DESCRIBE` query to get closer to your expected result. For example, we could amend it to not only describe `ex:toExport` but also all resources `?x` that are IRIs connected to `ex:toExport` via one of wanted properties:

```
DESCRIBE ex:toExport ?x
WHERE {
      ex:toExport ?p ?x .
      FILTER(isIRI(?x))
      FILTER(STRSTARTS(STR(?p), STR(rdf:)) || STRSTARTS(STR(?p), STR(shacl:)))
}
```

This result will retrieve all the data you want, but it still doesn't solve problem 2: it won't limit the returned properties to the ones you expect but will return *all* properties of `ex:toExport`, and of `?x`.

Filtering those unwanted properties out can of course be done in post-processing, but whether that is suitable for your scenario depends on the amount of 'unwanted' properties that are in your data in the first place.

One last caveat: the exact result of a `DESCRIBE` query is implementation-dependent. *Most* implementations return some form of blank node closure, but there are variations. Check the documentation of your SPARQL engine (or give it a test spin to see what it does).